# CSS3 color transition

Tags: css, transition

I want to add this transition effect to my website: http://www.formuswithlove.se/ (when you arrive to the next anchor the background-color change)

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does it mean to "arrive to the next anchor?"

Comment: I mean depending on the scroll position

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this can be done via pure CSS, but you can just check the scroll amount on a `window.scroll` event and update the background color for the body (or container element).  You may also like to have a transition.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 500) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"
    }
    else {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "transparent"
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GnX8A/1/

Comment: Thanks it works but the body background-color must change when the scroll reached a specific div. Because when I resize the window ( and the body's height is bigger) the color doesn't change properly